# How do I change URL without reloading page? - WITH A TWIST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, redirect

I am looking to remove a certain amount of a page URL without reloading.

I have looked on StackOverflow for the answer and there are a few close answers but not what I'm looking for really.

I do not want to use the hash function and if possible, avoid using the HTML5 version because HTML5 isn't the ratified standard yet and for the website this will be used on, I wouldn't be at all surprised is some of the clients used IE6.

I would prefer if it wasn't an extremely complicated solution with 400 lines of code (at that cost I'd rather just reload the page to be honest).

**I forgot to mention this, critical, part of the question**

```
The user is directed from a different page with this string via PHP. So for example:

user submits a form with errors. Let's say the form is on /myform.php

The user gets headed to /index.php?string
```

**carry on as normal**

What I have:

This is an example URL that I wish to edit without reloading:

http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?string

**Wait! ?string has a use on /index.php**

index.php will use $_GET['string']; and display a message to the user

I have used JQuery to remove the message after 4 seconds like this:

```
<div id="pagemsg"><?php echo $string; ?></div>

<script language="javascript">
    setTimeout( "$('#pagemsg').fadeOut();", 4000);
</script>
```

This works all well and the message disappears after 4 seconds. However I'm left with this URL:

http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?string

I don't want this string anymore because **?string** has done its job!

I would like to remove the **?string** without reloading the while page.

Is there any solution that can help me?

Also,

I don't mind if I have to use the HTML5 push function but is there a fall-back solution for the browsers that don;t support HTML5?

**Why did I put WITH A TWIST in the title? Well, my requirements are different to the questions I have seen so far. Correct me if I'm wrong and I will change it.**

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: your question title definitely had a twist in the end! :)

Comment: @raidenace Thank you, I am thinking of making a sequel.

Comment: Those are your only two options. Hash or history.push. Usually the fallback to history.push is to just use the hash. Without just staying on the same url and relying on ajax for page loading and never changing the url, that is it. Your only other semi option is to store the message in `?string` to session and header redirect instead of sending the page body. Then you can echo out from the session the message in the next loaded page and unset the session variable.

Comment: you definitely should - I would read the sh!t out of it!

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Actually. That's not a bad idea... Instead of a session I could store it as a cookie and do it that way. Then I just have to read the cookie data and destroy the cookie after use. Sessions or cookies I'll try. Thanks for the great idea!

Comment: Use a spare 20-cent IE6 vulnerability to hack into your clients' machines and install IE11, then skin it to look like IE6. Probably just as easy as what you're attempting.

Comment: I do not think you can change the URL without reloading the page. That would be a serious security flaw - what would happen if I opened a page called 'myduplicatebank.com' which has the exact UI as a genuine bank website and a few seconds later the script in the malicious site changes the URL without loading the site so that someone may come in and enter his creds thinking he is in the bank site? Or is it that you can use javascript only to change a part of the URL and not the whole?

Comment: @raidenace 1. the OP wants to change the url **after** the hostname 2. HTML5 already supports a function like this, but the OP wants this to work in old browsers

Comment: @raidenace You haven't seen the new history.push api I take it? You can add entries to the browsers history and change the URI or path (the part after the host name). This isn't changing the complete host to another site.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - I was just typing that about the whole URL. Ok that makes sense - and No, I havent taken a look at the push api in detail, being more of a server-side coder... *(looks sheepish)* *sigh* Uncle Douglas is gonna FRY me for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no. That's why they added `pushState`.

However, it looks like you are trying to accomplish a fairly common scenario known as **flash messaging**. This is often done using the user's session to store a message to show on the next request (and then delete it).

Example:

```
function doImportStuff() {
    // ...
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'important stuff was done';
    // ...
}

function showBoringPage() {
    // ...
    if (isset($_SESSION['message']) {
        echo '<b>' . $_SESSION['message'] . '</b>';
        unset($_SESSION['message']);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Jonathan Kuhn posted a comment directly on my question saying the same thing. This is the most appropriate approach to what I require.

Answer (score 0):

The only method I know of is this:

```js
if (history && history.pushState){
   history.pushState(null, null, '/new/url');
}
```

But this is HTML5 and won't work in your case..
For old browsers - and you: [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/)

Comment: Thank you for your input. I forgot to mention in the question that the user is sent from another page with that string. So using the history functions would actually just send the user back to the last page throwing another error and ultimately an infinite redirect loop. @Jonathan Kuhn suggested sessions to transport information that way which is probably my best option. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @ASweatyWombat yeah but I posted the code for future readers, the link was for you.